# Easily importing c++ libraries and dependencies on windows

Tags: c++, windows, dependency-management

I want to use some of the great libraries out there (e.g. cgal), but don't know how (have been exclusively writing my own code so far).
It seems every library requires a different process in order to use it (at least on windows)

I'm currently using Clion as an IDE in Windows 10 with minGW. I've tried using the Conan dependency manager but couldn't get it to work (and the documentation/video tutorials are not done very well).

Is there a recommended simple way to do it?

Is using vcpkg with visual studio a good way to go about it?

edit: for clarification, I am an academic physicist developing scientific simulations mostly to be used by myself, so I don't have to package my code with all the dependencies included.

Thanks.

Comment: CMake usually works pretty good for me. I have a single folder where I compile all my libraries to and have it on the path so `find_package` works well.

Comment: Unfortunately there really no simple way. Each library indeed requires different approach and there is nothing to do about it. Windows as a platform is no exception.

Comment: Each compiler has options for linking to external libs and for where to find them. The required libs for a package is something that the package itself must say some where in its docs.

Comment: Looks like cgal uses CMake. https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/Examples-and-Demo-Programs You may want to spend a few days and familiarize yourself with CMake.

Comment: @drescherjm Don't confuse the usage of CMake for building the package and the usage for your own app.

Comment: You probably want to use it for both. Like many other libraries that use CMake.

Comment: Do you really have to spend so much time (several days according to @drescherjm) to get familiarized with cmake, just in order to use libraries?
No automatic tool that does it for you, at least for the most common libraries?

Comment: CMake becomes good as soon as you have many many files, with many different compilers or different targets. If not, use the IDE features for linking with libraries. And no, "automatic tool" is not that "automatic".

Comment: Actually getting familiar with cmake won't automatically let you use libraries. The problem is that not all the libraries use cmake on the first place and even when they do they sometimes do it in twisted unpredictable manner. And cmake as a "global magic macros"-based language is not pleasant to debug.

Comment: Did anyone here try to use Visual C++ with vcpkg? supposedly it work automagically (the tutorial makes it look easy peasy). For some reason it didn't work for me even though I followed the tutorial to the letter